# Воспроизвести aero фон при контакте со сторонами экрана

Tags: c#

Как воспроизвести `aero` фон при контакте со сторонами экрана, если `formBorderStyle = None`,
вот как на скриншоте!

[image: big image]

Answer (score 1):

Все как обычно, нужно [гуглить](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Aero+Peek+winapi&oq=Aero+Peek+winapi&gs_l=hp.3...309.309.0.603.1.1.0.0.0.0.33.33.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.Mp6OztWC87w&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.bGE&fp=9d0b80dba4646286&biw=1613&bih=957).
Выдачу сюда копипастить не буду.

Comment: а причем тут Aero Pick к ресайзу окна?
"Aero Peek — позволяет отобразить рабочий стол и все находящиеся на нем значки и гаджеты, не сворачивая при этом окон запущенных программ, которые его перекрывают"
Сразу просто не переходил по вашей ссылке, а щас вернулся к этой теме..

Comment: Не при чем. Ресайз окна - это другая тема. Рисует такие эффекты фича под названием Aero Peek, которая принадлежит DWM. С ним вам и нужно взаимодействовать. API гуглится, как я уже показал.

Comment: Что такое dwm более-менее разобрался , нашел как сделать форму в стиле aero и как поменять иконку при наведение. А как нарисовать то что нужно не нашел.
Или это нужно делать "вручную", брать создавать glass форму и имитировать еффекты aero - но это как то тупо..
П.с Я понимаю что наверное что то упустил но пытаюсь разобраться уже не первый день.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450223/windows-aero-peek-api

Comment: читал эту тему, но так и не разобрался в 3ем и 4м параметре поэтому и не удалось использовать код.


    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "#113", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern uint DwmpActivateLivePreview(uint switch,  IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr c, uint d);
    DwmpActivateLivePreview(1, Handle, topmostWindowHandle, 1);//activate
    DwmpActivateLivePreview(0, Handle, topmostWindowHandle, 1);//deactivate

Comment: Таки я неправильно понял вопрос. С Aero Peek никаких проблем нет, но по всей видимости, вам нужно рисовать фейковое пустое неактивное окно, как это делает фича Aero Snap. Сходу не гуглится. Я бы создал для этого настоящую форму. Есть [способ][1] заставить DWM рисовать ее как неактивую.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133723/how-can-i-force-aero-to-draw-a-borderless-window-as-if-it-were-active-even-if-i

Comment: Спасибо буду пробывать.
П.с документации по aero win api почти нет, и это печально...