# Воспроизвести aero фон при контакте со сторонами экрана

Tags: c#, winapi, функции, windows-aero, windows

Так и не решил проблему о которой говорил в этой [теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/205612/c-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-aero-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0), частично нашел решение

```
 protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;

                cp.Style |= (int)0x00040000L;//(int)0x00C00000L ; //WS_SIZEBOX;
                return cp;
            }
        }
```

но это только добавляет границы за которые можно расширять размер элемента, но основная проблема как заменить стандартный title bar осталась, я пытаюсь сделать что похожее на  [title bar в visual studio](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-YgJQd4rVLBY/UV_xXIdBP3I/AAAAAAAAAMI/JqOasmjyYpI/s1302/1.jpg)
[image: title bar в visual studio]
перерыл dwm и [windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) но так и понял какая функция вызывается для отрисовки демо.
Я понимаю что по 2 темы создавать плохо, но пытаюсь решить эту проблему больше недели.
Вариант самому создать форму и ее использовать для фона - не подойдет.

**Решение:**

```
 private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
 private const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref message);

            if (message.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST )
                            message.Result = (IntPtr)HTCAPTION;
        }
```

Comment: Если честно, не понял связи между `title bar'`ом `Visual studio` и формулировкой предыдущей темы, вернее, мне вообще непонятна эта формулировка. Можете по-русски описать проблему?

Comment: Мне нужно заменить стандартный title bar формы на мой, но так же что бы остался весь функционал, т.е с помошью title bar  можно перемещать форму по экрану ,если title bar окно перетащить форму к стороне экрана то появляется демо как форма будет развернута.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это уже другое дело!

> Мне нужно заменить стандартный title bar формы на мой, но так же что бы остался весь функционал, т.е с помошью title bar можно перемещать форму по экрану

Это делается так:

1. Из стилей окна удаляется `WS_CAPTION` (`0x00C00000L`)
2. Обрабатывается `WM_NCHITTEST` таким образом, чтобы при прохождении мыши над Вашим `title bar`'ом системе возвращался код `HTCAPTION`.

это позволит пользователю таскать окно за Ваш `title bar`

> если title bar окно перетащить форму к стороне экрана то появляется демо как форма будет развернута.

Если я правильно понял, тут требуется, чтобы при приближении окна к краям раб. стола, показывался вид (демо), который будет соответствовать вашему окну, если пользователь отпустит в этот момент кнопку мыши.

С точки зрения `API` этот процесс может быть реализован двумя способами.

**Первый**: перехватываем `WM_MOVING` и корректируем `RECT`, приходящий в `lParam` таким образом, чтобы он соответствовал Вашему "демо". В таком случае, в зависимости от настроек системы, при перемещении окна либо будет появляться "демо", либо само окно будет выступать в роли "демо". Это с моей точки зрения, правильный вариант, т.к. не нарушает концепцию перемещения окон в `Windows`.

**Второй**: аналогично - перехватываем `WM_MOVING` но не корректируем `RECT`, приходящий в `lParam`. Вместо этого, в моменты, когда требуется показать "демо" - рисуем его XOR-кистью, на девайсе экрана (`GetDC( NULL )`) к примеру: с помощью `DrawFocusRect`. В таком случае, чтобы стереть последний "демо", нужно вызвать `DrawFocusRect` на `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`.

Проблема второго метода в том, что он не зависит от настроек `Windows` (по-русски звучит как-то так: "Отображать содержимое окна при перетаскивании"), но такой метод, в свою очередь, дает возможность рисовать произвольное "демо" заказчика.

**p.s.:** для полноты эффекта, требуется обрабатывать еще и `WM_SIZING`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все оказалось гениально просто.
П.с код добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Пожалуйста, но этот код позволяет перетаскивать окно вообще за любую область. Я так понимаю, это допустимое упущение :)

Comment: Это просто пример, главное я понял суть, остальное сделать не проблема)

Comment: @mega ,а не подскажите как изменить wndProc для класса унаследованного от Panel, что бы возвращать сообщение для формы?
Или отправлять сообщение в WindowProc на прямую?

Comment: Все оказалось не так просто))
WM_NCHITTEST обрабатывается формой пока курсор не ушел на другой элемент формы (или за ее пределы), т.е я так понимаю нужно самому вызывать CallWindowProc ?

Comment: >как изменить wndProc для класса унаследованного от Panel, что бы возвращать сообщение для формы?

Попробуйте задать новый вопрос по этому поводу, только подробнее опишите проблему, т.к. мне, например, эта формулировка опять непонятна

>WM_NCHITTEST обрабатывается формой пока курсор не ушел на другой элемент формы (или за ее пределы), т.е я так понимаю нужно самому вызывать CallWindowProc

`WM_NCHITTEST` всегда посылается окну, над которым находится курсор. "Другой элемент формы" - это другое окно, следовательно сообщение посылается уже ему. Опишите задачу подробнее, зачем Вам другие элементы