# Вернуть сообщение из одного окна другому

Tags: c#, winapi

Есть форма и панель на ней . Как сделать так что бы при обработке WM_NCHITTEST  на панели возвращалось значение для формы. Т.е когда на панели обрабатывается WM_NCHITTEST  то для формы должно возвращаться сообщение HTCAPTION?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать перехватить `WM_NCHITTEST` у панели и вернуть код `TRANSPARENT`. Этот код означает, что "мышиный ввод" на данном контроле становится "прозрачным". Т.е., теоретически, в таком случае форма должна будет принимать `WM_NCHITTEST` даже если мышь находится над панелью.

p.s.: в продолжение обсуждения [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/209641/c-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-aero-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Comment: @mega, спасибо работает.
Остался последний вопрос:
Если допустим нет возможности обрабатывать сообщение которые передаются в метод WndProc, то нужно напрямую использовать функцию CallWindowProc ?

Comment: По поводу `CallWindowProc`: не очень понял, при чем здесь `CallWindowProc`. Вы имеете ввиду, что **хотели бы обрабатывать какие-то сообщения дочерних компонент так, как если бы они приходили к самой форме?** В таких случаях существует 2 инструмента:

1. уведомления компонента
2. cабклассинг.

В первом случае, большинство компонент имеют возможность уведомлять "форму" о какой-то своей активности (например, через `WM_COMMAND` или `WM_NOTIFY`). Во втором случае, Вы можете переписать процедуру окна компонента, чтобы проконтролировать или изменить обработку каких-то сообщений этого компонента.

Comment: p.s.: увы - регламент форума не позволяет давать расширенные ответы в комментариях. Если возникают подобные вопросы - задавайте их отдельно, в формате `Q&A`, чтобы не ограничивать число и качество ответов.

Comment: " Вы имеете ввиду, что хотели бы обрабатывать какие-то сообщения дочерних компонент так, как если бы они приходили к самой форме?"
Нет, у меня есть класс(наследует Control) , в нем есть панель которая является новым title bar и я пытаюсь сделать что то на подобие библиотек, а значить я не смогу добавить свой код в wndProc.
 
p.s 
"задавайте их отдельно, в формате Q&A, чтобы не ограничивать число и качество ответов" 

а как это сделать?

Comment: >и я пытаюсь сделать что то на подобие библиотек, а значить я не смогу добавить свой код в wndProc

Вот это место мне непонятно.

>а как это сделать?

Так же, как Вы это сделали, задав вопрос: "Вернуть сообщение из одного окна другому". Главное - опишите подробнее проблему.

Comment: создал http://hashcode.ru/questions/210547/c-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-htcaption-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-wndproc