# Возвращение HTCAPTION для окна без изменения wndProc

Tags: c#, winapi

Продолжение [этой темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/210107/c-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83). Есть класс Foo (к примеру), который является  контейнером, в нем есть панель которая и будет titlte bar. Т.е добавить код в класс основного окна я не могу и поэтому не возможности обрабатывать сообщение в wndProc. Но как тогда вернуть результат HTCAPTION для этого окна.

Comment: Вам надо вернуть HTCAPTION кому? Если в ответ на window message NC_HITTEST, приходящий из WndProc, думаю, ответ самоочевиден.

Я бы посоветовал переделать архитектуру приложения так, чтобы панель, представляющая собой title bar, имела доступ/влияние на WndProc.

Comment: "Вам надо вернуть HTCAPTION кому? "
Основному окну в котором находиться мой элемент.

"Если в ответ на window message NC_HITTEST, приходящий из WndProc, думаю, ответ самоочевиден."
Не совсем понял.
Мне нужно на WM_NCHITTEST для панели нужно вернуть HTCAPTION для основной формы.

Comment: unsafe и Win API. Если окно, заголовок которого вы хотите получить, создано не в вашем процессе, то поможет вам только FindWindowEx

Comment: Причем тут другой процес?
Это окно родитель моего элемента.

Comment: @cyber_ua: ну, можно и возвращать основному окну: пусть оно на WM_HITTEST найдёт контрол в нужной точке, и спросит найденный контрол о том, какой у него HITTEST-код. Если у вас WPF, это прекрасно организуется через attached properties. Если WinForms, придётся вручную.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> пусть оно на WM_HITTEST найдёт контрол в нужной точке, и спросит найденный контрол о том, какой у него HITTEST-код

@VladD, этого делать [не надо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/210107#210110). У ТС, по всей видимости, другой вопрос: как не меняя `WndProc` основного окна, добавить его эксклюзивный функционал.
 --
@cyber_ua, а есть возможность **наследовать** класс основного окна от другого класса окна?
 --
Другими словами, есть ли возможность задействовать [суперклассинг](http://allasm.ru/urok_22.php)?
 --
Собственно, по-моему, для решения задачи сложно придумать другой способ:

1. Cоздайте свой класс окна, в котором динамически на `WM_CREATE` добавьте дочернюю панель, у которой `WM_NCHITTEST` будет возвращать `TRANSPARENT`, а в основной `WndProc` будет обработка `WM_NCHITTEST` с `HTCAPTION`.
2. Выделите эту `WndProc` в динамическую библиотеку.
3. В ее `DllMain` пропишите регистрацию и удаление своего класса.
4. Подключите ее в произвольный проект и наследуйте основную форму от своего класса в `CreateParams`.

Вы получите возможность подключать свой эксклюзивный компонент в произвольные проекты, причем, это будут даже не обязательно проекты `Си#`.

p.s.: хочу только заметить, что VS не использует для отображения своего заголовка дочерние окна, она просто рисует заголовок на основной форме, это более "продвинутый" способ, т.к. требует гораздо меньше ресурсов.

Comment: "Собственно, по-моему, для решения задачи сложно придумать другой способ"
Суть в том:
1.создать класс который наследуется от Form.
2.добавить нужный код и потом что бы его наследовала(этот класс) пользовательская форма?

Про суперклассинг не совсем понял.

Comment: >Суть в том

Да, суть в этом.

>Про суперклассинг не совсем понял

**Сабклассинг** - это подмена процедуры окна в какой-то момент времени, а **суперклассинг** - это **наследование** процедуры окна.  
 --  
Понятия почти одинаковые, но в случае с суперклассингом процедура окна подменяется **на этапе регистрации класса окна**.  
 --  
В случае который я описал с `DLL`, получится, что любое сообщение, посланное в пользовательскую форму будет сначала обработано процедурой окна **пользователя**, а затем, если пользователь не решит иначе - Вашей.

Comment: Т.е. Ваш добавленный функционал будет за пределами процедуры окна пользователя, в Вашей библиотеке.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.
Не посоветуете литературу где можно почитать про работу с winapi?

Comment: Пожалуйста!

>Не посоветуете литературу где можно почитать про работу с winapi?
`WinAPI` - достаточно большая система с множеством подсистем. В обычной сегодняшней жизни, весь этот материал программисту не требуется. А вот по оконной и графической подсистеме у Петцольда есть хорошее [пособие](http://www.softtime.ru/cpp_info/petzold.php), можете почитать. И не надо смотреть, что оно старое, эта подсистема достаточно консервативна, чтобы время сильно на нее влияло. Главное - чтобы текст автора был понятен.

Comment: Правда, ни одна книга Вам не заменит [подробнейшей документации от разработчика](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Библиотека_MSDN). Так что, советую: сначала почитать пособие на русском, а места, которые особенно заинтересовали - закрепить в `MSDN`.